# combobox additional values?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a piece of JS here for my combobox. it works fine.

```
@wire(getThemes,{ cabinetId: '$selectCab', brandId: '$selectBrand'})
wiredThemes({error, data }){
           if (data) {
        this.themes = data.map((th) => Object.assign({}, { label: th.Name, value: th.Id }));
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

You can see where i assign label and value, but what if i need a second 'value' like so

```
@wire(getThemes,{ cabinetId: '$selectCab', brandId: '$selectBrand'})
wiredThemes({error, data }){
           if (data) {
        this.themes = data.map((th) => Object.assign({}, { label: th.Name, value: th.Id, value2: th.customIntegerField__c}));
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Because later on when you select the option in the combobox i want to do the following

```
handleThemeSelect(event){
    this.selectTheme = event.detail.value;
    if(event.detail.value2 > 0){
          //do something
          }else if(event.detail.value2 <0) {
           //do something else
              }
}
```

Because when i look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/specification It looks like only one value can be held. ......SO i would have to get the value and then do ANOTHER apex callout to get the field value to then perform the else if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the extra values in the parent component, at the same time you add to your theme list.

Might be hard to use `map` here, but you can use a `forEach` instead.

Something like:

```
let themes = [];
let themeExtras = {};
data.forEach( th => {
  let theme = Object.assign({}, { label: th.Name, value: th.Id, value2: th.customIntegerField__c });
  this.themes.push(theme);
  this.themeExtras[theme.value] = theme;
});
```

As you can see, I've put the extras in an object that we retrieve in the handler.

```
handleThemeSelect(event){
  this.selectTheme = event.detail.value;
  let value2 = this.themeExtras[event.detail.value];
  if(value2 > 0){
      //do something
  }
  else if(value2 <0) {
       //do something else
  }
}
```

You will likely need some error checking as well here.